# Which performance have cPython sets in comparison to lists?

Tags: python, cpython

I have just found these [performance notes for cPython lists](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm#performance):

Time needed for python lists to ....

- ... get or set an individual item: O(1)
- ... append an item to the list: worst O(n^2), but usually O(1)
- ... insert an item: O(n), where n is the number of elements after the inserted one
- ... remove an item: O(n)

Now I would like to know the same performance characteristics for cPython sets. Also, I would like how fast iteration over the list / set is. I am especially interested in large lists / sets.

Comment: Appending to a list usually O(1) - it can only go to O(n*n) for large lists when more memory needs to be allocated. Inserting an item will have the same worst case performance.

Comment: Appending an item to a list is not O(n^2).  The page you linked is confusing inserting one item with inserting N items, which is an error of an order of complexity.

Comment: @Glenn: even for inserting `n` items, you wouldn't get `O(n*2)` complexity unless the array always allocated *exactly* the amount of memory it needs.

Comment: @Andre: you still end up with O(n*2) complexity even if the list always over-allocates by a constant number of entries, which I believe is the case for Python lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the Python "specification" does not impose specific data structures for implementation of lists, dictionaries or sets, so this can't be answered "officially".  If you're only concerned about CPython (the reference implementation), then we can throw in some un-official complexities.  You might want to re-formulate your question to target a specific Python implementation.

In any case, the complexities you mentioned can't be right.  Supposing a dynamically-resized array implementation, appending an item is amortized `O(1)`: most often you simple copy the new value, and in the worst case, you need to re-allocate, copying all `n` items, plus the new one.  Next, inserting has exactly the same worst case scenario, so it has the same upper bound on complexity, but in the best case, it only moves `k` items, where `k` is the number of items *past* the position where you're inserting.

Comment: In general it's safe to assume CPython.  Code must be able to rely on the complexity of operations on core types--that's a fundamental necessity for using them.  Specified or not, all implementations must match the reference implementation if they expect compatibility.  (There are a couple gotchas; off-hand, `s += x` for strings comes to mind.)

Comment: @Glenn: although it *is* very likely that all implementations will implement Python lists using dynamically-resized arrays, no one *must* match the reference implementation on anything unless it's in the specification.

Comment: No, you *must* match the reference implementation if you expect to be able to run production Python code.  If you don't, then software will break.

Comment: @Glenn: No, you only need to match the external interface. Code will not break if a list is implemented differently, your code may just run with a different complexity than in the reference implementation.

Comment: @Kanchi: In the real world, a one-second algorithm taking ten minutes due to a fundamental O(1) operation being O(n) is broken.

Comment: Ah, but you preclude the possibility that the non-reference implementation might actually be _better_ than the reference implementation. While this is fairly unlikely for fundamental things, Java's implementation of _foo_ (and thus Jython's) might be better than CPython's.

Comment: @Glenn: it doesn't matter.  You can't assume that something which differs from the reference implementation, yet not specified is "non-compliant" and *must* be fixed, or there would be no point in leaving wiggle room in the spec, or even writing a spec in the first place.  You should avoid writing code that depends on some specific internals to CPython, because it makes your code non-portable to other implementations.   The classic example is people relying on a reference-counted garbage collector.

Comment: @Chinmay: In general, you can't have better big-O performance for one operation without having worse big-O performance for another.  @Caron: I didn't say "non-compliant"--those are your words.  You've missed the point.  Again, you must match the reference implementation *if you expect compatibility*.  If you don't mind breaking lots of programs, you can change complexity all you want, but in practice, an implementation that uses linked lists for `list` is just broken.